# Discord.py Rewrite/Python, an if is not running

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this code:

```
@bot.command()
async def allBots(ctx):
    bots = []
    for x in range(len(ctx.guild.members)):
        if ctx.guild.members[x].bot:
            print('Found a bot! its name is ' + ctx.guild.members[x].display_name)
            bots.append(ctx.guild.members[x].display_name)
        if x == len(ctx.guild.members):
            print('Found every bot in a server!')
            a = print(*bots, split=', ')
            await ctx.send(str(a))
```

It's supposed to run through each member in the server, and if the member its looking at is a bot. it will be added to a list and at the end of all this, it will print every element of the list to chat, but the if at the bottom isn't running. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What are the values that you expect `x` to have each time through the loop? what is the largest value that you expect `x` to have? How does that match up with your last condition?

Comment: Anyway, if you want something to happen one time, after all the processing in a loop... just put it *after* the loop, unindented.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes, i know that now... when i made that original code i thought that it would still do the code after it at the beginning of the loop. but i was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last if-statement will only print every bot user in the server IF the amount of members-1 (`x`) is the same as the amount of members there are in the server (`len(ctx.guild.members)`). Essentially, this condition will never succeed. I assume you want your bot to send a message at the end of the for-loop. If so, that's simple: remove the conditional and unindent the code you want to run so it's outside the for-loop:

```
@bot.command()
async def allBots(ctx):
    bots = []

    for x in range(len(ctx.guild.members)):
        if ctx.guild.members[x].bot:
            print('Found a bot! its name is ' + ctx.guild.members[x].display_name)
            bots.append(ctx.guild.members[x].display_name)

    print('Found every bot in a server!')
    a = ', '.join(bots)  # Don't use print() to store a string; it returns None
    await ctx.send(a)
```

As @derw said, you can more efficiently run through members in the server just by directly iterating through `ctx.guild.members`:

```
@bot.command()
async def allBots(ctx):
    bots = []

    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        if member.bot:
            print('Found a bot! its name is', member.display_name)
            bots.append(member.display_name)

    print('Found every bot in a server!')
    a = ', '.join(bots)
    await ctx.send(a)
```

Comment: i fixed it already with what @derw said, but thanks for the help for what i could do to fix my original un efficient code.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly your code is over complicated and convoluted, it confuses me trying to follow what you are trying to accomplish.

Here is a very simple rewrite of what you have:

```
bots = []
for member in ctx.guild.members:
    if member.bot:
        bots.append(member.display_name)

print(', '.join(bots))
```

Comment: oh, thanks for telling me... i only started doing discord.py and python a couple months ago

Answer (score 0):

You could make us of [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) and [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to simplify your code, also you don't need to check if your loop ended from inside the loop you can just put your code outside of the loop so it will be executed once the loop ended. Here is one way to achieve what you want:

```
@bot.command() 
async def allBots(ctx): 
    bots = map(lambda member: member.display_name, filter(lambda member: member.bot, ctx.guild.members)) # Filter members that are bots then get their display names 
    
    # Loop through every bot's display name
    for bot in bots: 
        print("Found a bot! Its name is", bot)

    print("Found every bot in the server")
    a = ', '.join(bots)
    print(a)
    await ctx.send(a)
```